# Finding XPATH for an DOB

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, ui-automation

I am not able to locate the xpath for the DOB field for the following page as the right click is disabled in the DOB calendar. Any leads will be helpful.

For example, I am trying to select the DOB as 1st Mar,2004

https://pos-diy.iiflinsurance.com/form/proposer-form?quote_id=dARV3Hz22VvXFwtRy5Ev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to click on the Calendar and then Select a date.

You can parse the value using `execute_script`

**Code:**

```
driver.get("https://pos-diy.iiflinsurance.com/form/proposer-form?quote_id=dARV3Hz22VvXFwtRy5Ev")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[placeholder='Full Name']"))).send_keys('Apratim Chaudhuri')
dob = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='date']")))

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = arguments[1]", dob, "2004-03-01")
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: somehow with the parsing method you have mentioned, the date is getting populated successfully in the field. Due to some application restriction, until I open the calendar and select the date by clicking or by pressing ENTER, the application is not accepting the same.As a result, I am not able to navigate to the next page due to an error. Do you know a method of after parsing the date like above, Can I click on the DOB button and just press ENTER using selenium python?  https://app.iifl.riskcovry.com/form/proposer-form?quote_id=dXyQgcTP4HdYUmEYR2dC

Comment: Please feel free to create a new ticket for new requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This XPath expression will match:

```xml
"//input[@formcontrolname='dob']"
```

Or even this

```xml
"//input[@formcontrolname]"
```